# How to fix "sharing violation" message when editing hosts file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hosts

I'm running textpad as administrator. When I try to save the changes, I get a message "Encountered a sharing violation while accessing C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts."

I checked using Process Explorer and the only handles it finds that reference hosts are "System".

How do I get around this?

I have attempted both replacing the hosts file by either editing it, pasting the new version in and saving it, and by copying the new "hosts" file as administrator. Latest attempt got a message "file is open in system". I'm running ZoneAlarm for security.

Comment: Is the user, attempting to modify the hosts file, an Administrator?  Is that user elevating the permissions of the text editor to that of an Administrator?  What security software do you have installed?  Please edit your question to include this vital requried information.

Comment: Your firewall or antivirus software may be preventing access to the hosts file.

Comment: I always copy the hosts file to a path outside of the windows folder, then edit it, and then copy it back. Explorer will then ask for administrative permissions and overwrite the file. You can also set permissions on the file, but it may break the hosts file until permissions are restored.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ZoneAlarm lock the hosts file, then it prevents us access to hosts file. We can try to uninstall the ZoneAlarm.

Then we try to grant hosts file administrator privileges and access the hosts file.

When it is complete the above, reinstall the ZoneAlarm.

Answer (score 0):

Daisy Zhou's answer led me to this: ZoneAlarm's firewall settings (advanced) have a "lock hosts file" checkbox. That option is normally turned off by default, but my system had it turned on. I turned it back off, and put the new hosts file in place using my administrator ID. I then restored the lock. No uninstall of ZoneAlarm was necessary.